# Conditionally Sum values in a Column Based on Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that describes a closed path of bus stops, as well as the buses that drive along the path:

```
stop_id | order_in_route | time_from_last_stop | bus_id
------------------------------------------------------
3       | 1              | 5                   | 3
6       | 2              | 10                  | NULL
2       | 3              | 5                   | NULL
1       | 4              | 15                  | 2
9       | 5              | 10                  | NULL
```

Things to note:

1. stop_id is unique
2. order_in_route is unique
3. time_from_last_stop is not unique
4. bus_id is unique (unless NULL)
5. the table must contain at least 1 NON-NULL bus_id

This basically means that each loop of the path crosses every stop once and only once, and each stop has its own unique order in the route. Finally, there is at least 1 bus driving along the route at any given time, and if multiple buses are driving, they are unique, and are never at the same stop at once.

In this case, the circular path would be (with the time between each stop noted within the ->):

```
... stop 9 -5> stop 3 -10> stop 6 -5> stop 2 -15> stop 1 -10> stop 9 -5> stop 3...
```

Currently, there is a bus at stop 3 and stop 1. So, the time for a bus to arrive at these 2 stops is 0, and the bus arriving at each stop is the bus currently there:

```
stop_id | order_in_route | time_for_bus_to_arrive | bus_id
-----------------------------------------------------------
3       | 1              | 0                      | 3
1       | 4              | 0                      | 2
```

To calculate the time for a bus to arrive at every stop without a bus currently there, sum the *time_from_last_stop*s for yourself and every stop behind you without a bus currently at the stop, until you reach a stop with a bus currently at the stop. Also, to calculate the bus that will arrive at it, you find the closest bus behind you.

For stop 6:

```
time_for_a_bus_to_arrive(stop 6) = time_from_last_stop(stop 6)
                                 = 10
bus_id(stop 6) = 3
```

For stop 2:

```
time_for_a_bus_to_arrive(stop 2) = time_from_last_stop(stop 2) + time_from_last_stop(stop 6)
                                 = 5 + 10
                                 = 15
bus_id(stop 2) = 3
```

For stop 9:

```
time_for_a_bus_to_arrive(stop 9) = time_from_last_stop(stop 9)
                                 = 10
bus_id(stop 9) = 2
```

So the final table should be:

```
stop_id | order_in_route | time_for_bus_to_arrive | bus_id
------------------------------------------------------
3       | 1              | 0                      | 3
6       | 2              | 10                     | 3
2       | 3              | 15                     | 3
1       | 4              | 0                      | 2
9       | 5              | 5                      | 2
```

My question, is **how to achieve this with a single SELECT query in MySQL?** I do not know how to implement the human-readable logic above to a statement in MySQL.

What I've tried so far is (#'s note commented code that I do not know how to structure):

```
SELECT stop_id, order_in_route, SUM(time_from_last_stop
  WHERE bus_id IS NULL # AND order_in_route is earlier in path AND is after a bus_id that is NOT NULL
) AS time_for_bus_to_arrive, (SELECT bus_id
  FROM firstTable
  WHERE bus_id IS NOT NULL # AND closest behind in path
) AS bus_id
FROM firstTable;
```

This is clearly improper syntax, but I think the idea is clear.

Comment: On my phone and can't easily write it out now, but one approach is just to join the table to itself using a non-equi join on the order_in_route column. Someone will answer this quickly, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SQL Server syntax, utilizing window functions (I duplicated your table and got the results that you're looking for) but I think there is similar syntax in MySQL:

```
SELECT stop_id, 
       order_in_route, 
       next_bus, 
       arrival_time
FROM (SELECT Stops.stop_id, Stops.order_in_route, tA.next_bus, tA.prev_order_in_route,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Stops.bus_id IS NULL THEN Stops.time_from_last_stop ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tA.prev_order_in_route ORDER BY Stops.order_in_route) AS arrival_time,
             MAX(tA.prev_order_in_route) OVER (PARTITION BY Stops.order_in_route ORDER BY Stops.order_in_route) AS max_prev_order_in_route
      FROM Stops LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_in_route AS prev_order_in_route, bus_id AS next_bus 
                            FROM Stops 
                            WHERE bus_id IS NOT NULL) tA ON tA.prev_order_in_route <= Stops.order_in_route ) tB 
WHERE prev_order_in_route = max_prev_order_in_route         
ORDER BY order_in_route
```

Important in this process is calculating, for each stop, what the `order_in_route` is for the stop that the next bus is at. I call this `prev_order_in_route`. So for example, for the first three stops `prev_order_in_route = 1`, and for the last two stops `prev_order_in_route = 4`. When this made up number changes, then we know that we've hit a stop that has a bus at it, and so we need to reset the SUM( ) function that calculates arrival time for the next bus.

Unless there's some huge performance enhancement, I would probably avoid doing all of this in SQL if possible (for instance, this processing could all be done more transparently by your server side code if this is for a smartphone app or website).

And if doing it in SQL is a necessity, then break it out into separate pieces so that it doesn't look like a mess (in SQL Server we use things like common table expressions to achieve this functional decomposition).